# How can I solve this inequality?

Tags: inequality

Have a nice day, how can I solve this inequality?

$$a<b<-1$$

$$ |ax - b| \le  |bx-a|$$

what is the solution set for this inequality

Comment: Have you tried drawing the two sides of the inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squaring both sides,

$$a^2x^2-2abx+b^2 \leq b^2x^2-2abx+a^2$$

$$(a^2-b^2)x^2 \leq a^2-b^2$$

Since $a^2-b^2>0$, we can divide both sides by $a^2-b^2$ and preserve the sign of inequality.
$$x^2 \leq 1$$

$$|x|\leq 1$$

$$-1 \leq x \leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

There may be more efficient ways to do these but for clarity I like to break absolute values into cases:

Case 1: $ax -b \ge 0$ and $bx -a \ge 0$.

[This implies $ax \ge b\implies x \le b/a$ and likewise $x \le a/b$ so $x \le \min(a/b,b/a) = b/a < 1$.  Let's keep in mind $b/a < 1 < a/b$]

Then $|ax - b| \le |bx -a| \implies ax - b \le bx - a$

So $(a-b)x \le (b-a)$; $a < b$ so $(a - b) < 0$ so

$x \ge (b-a)/(a-b) = -1$

So $-1 \le x \le b/a < 1$.  **OR**

Case 2:  $ax -b <0$ and $bx-a < 0$.

[This implies $ax < b\implies x > b/a$ and $x > a/b$ so $x > \max(a/b,b/a) =a/b > 1$]

then $b - ax \le a - bx$ so

$(b - a) \le (a - b)x$ so

$(b-a)/(a-b) \ge x$ so $x \le -1$ which is a contradiction.

**OR**

Case 3:  $ax -b < 0$ and $bx - a \ge 0$

[which implies $ax < b\implies x >b/a > 1$ and $bx \ge a\implies x \le a/b \le 1$.  So $b/a < x \le a/b$.  Remember $b/a < 1 < a/b$]

So $b - ax \le bx - a$ so $(b+a) \le (a + b)x$.  Now (a+b) < 0. So

$(b+a)/(a+b) = 1 \ge x$

So $b/a < x \le 1$.

**OR**

Case 4:  $ax - b \ge 0$ and $bx - a < 0$

[which implies $ax \ge b \implies x\le b/a$ and $x > a/b$ so $a/b < x \le b/a$ which is a contradiction.]

So we know $-1 \le x \le b/a$ *OR* $b/a < x \le -1$ so combining the two results we know $-1 \le x \le 1$.

But there are probably more efficient ways to do this.